# Selenium: How can I verify the currently selected option in a dropdown?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, verification

I have a dropdown menu with several objects that can be chosen: [image: Dropdown]

I want to verify the default select option of 2 hours. I have done this so far with the following:

```
   def time_span_default(self):
    dropdown = Select(self.driver.find_element(*Elements.timespan_dropdown))
    default_option = dropdown.first_selected_option
    return default_option.text

 # If default_option.text == "2 hours" my testcase is verified and can continue...
```

However I also want to verify the text for the other objects once they are selected by me.

Can anyone advise what the best way to approach this would be if I want to verify the text of the *currently selected object* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_selected_option` should do the job even when you change the selected option. From the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.first_selected_option)

> The first selected option in this select tag (**or the currently selected option in a normal select**)

Comment: This method ended up working best for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example code you set `dropdown = Select...`

That select object has an attribute `options`, this will give you a list of elements for each option in the drop down menu, you can iterate the list and get the element text for your verification

In your case `dropdown.options` will return a list of 4 web elements, one for each time span.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I do see that `options` is an attribute I can call but I'm having difficulty understanding how to use it to verify the text of a currently selected option? Could you give any further details? 

Cheers

Comment: You don't need to select them to verify the text value, you can get the text value the same way you verified the default selection, by `element.text`, you can do the same for all other options, selected or not.

Comment: If you still want to select the option before verifying the text, just select them by index or value with the available methods and use the same method `first_selected_option` to verify

Answer (score 0):

if you look up the `<option>` by css_selector, you can get the selected one with

```
selected = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[selected]")
```